# Break loop without error in Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, exception, element

I am getting the following error when trying to parse the last page of my loop and exit the loop once the next (») button no longer exists: **selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: »**

Code:

```
while True:
    prices = driver.find_element_by_id('showAllGraphsButton')
    prices.click()
    time.sleep(6)
    s_container = driver.find_element_by_id('stockContainer')
    stocks = WebDriverWait(s_container, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "imageRow")))
    for stock in stocks:
        name = WebDriverWait(stock, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "auto-ellipsis"))).text
        stock_name.append(name)
        percentage = WebDriverWait(stock, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "return-value"))).text
        stock_percentage.append(percentage)
        price = WebDriverWait(stock, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "last-price"))).text
        stock_price.append(price)

        if len(driver.find_element_by_link_text('»').text) > 0:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('»').click()
            time.sleep(6)
        else:
            break

driver.quit()
```

Please may I have some guidance on how to successfully exit the loop when the element no longer exists.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use `try...except` block to break the loop without error. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: put "try" and "except" function in your code. With them the code don't return error, but it simply stop. If you want, you can repeat the loop in case of error, you can only put break at finish of try.
while True:
try:
#some code
break
except:
#some code